# Attempted BIOS update through spi

Tags: boot, laptop, bios

Like the title suggests, i flashed the bios the hard way. I had a password protected bios on my HP EliteBook 8470p and needed the virtualization option to be enabled for a virtual XP machine. I've tried a bunch of methods (all software) on resetting the factory password on the chip and none of them worked. After all these failed attempts I've told myself there must be a way and then I've bumped into this [tutorial](https://blog.altillimity.com/?p=47) showing how to program the W25Q128 bios chip with the help of a raspberry pi and flashrom through SPI. It seemed logic and simple as I have some experience with electronics, soldering, etc. All went good and nice until I've put the laptop back together and pressed the power button. It did nothing. Screen doesn't backlight, caps lock led (and any other leds) don't blink or anything except for the power one. When I connect the battery/AC adapter it lights up (constant) white and blinks orange continuously until i unplug the power. I was scared that the bios that I flashed was corrupt and I repeated the whole process just to reflash the old bios (I've backed up before hehe). I was kind of relaxed thinking it was going to work after I finish assembling it, only to be welcomed with the same result.
Now I ended up with a laptop which literally only turns on the power led when I plug it in/attach the battery. I've searched hp support for the blink code but no result.
It would've been much more convenient and easy if HP didn't decide not to provide smc.bin files anymore....
What should I do now? What's the problem? Why does it do nothing when I press the power button? How can I fix it?

Comment: I did desolder, program, and then resolder it every time, but I've got it sorted out this night, I've managed to find a bios dump for a 6470p on a Russian site. With nothing much left to lose I thought it was a good idea. And it was, it's working, posting, booting, and I have access to the BIOS without a password now 